# using angular js get data from codeigniter controller

Tags: angularjs, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I work with codeigniter with angular js.
I had created one controller name Car.one model name car_model.
In car controller i have created one method view () in which i am fetching data from the table that code file is

**Car Controller**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Car extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Car_model');
     }

     public function view()
     {
        $data = $this->db->get("cars")->result_array();
        echo json_encode($data);
     }
    }
```

i want to fetch data in json formate so had fetched that data and  echo json_encode($data);

now i want to retrieve that data in angualrjs.

**add_car View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
        <form method="post"  ng-submit="add(car_det)">
            Car name : <input type="text" ng-model="car_det.cname" name="name"><br>
            Car Image : <input type="file" custom-on-change="uploadFile" ng-model="car_det.cimage"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="add">
        </form>
        <br>
        <table>
            <tr><td>ID </td><td>Car Name</td><td>Car Image</td></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in otherdata">
                <td>{{x.id}}</td><td>{{x.cname}}</td><td>{{x.cimage}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("myctrl",function($scope,$http){
$http.get("<?=base_url()?>Car/view").then(function(response){
                $scope.otherdata = response.data;
            });
});
</script>
```

**

**Error :**

**While i writing this code in my file, problem is that it shows data in table format it is proper but also showing extra json array in starting of page.**

**I am getting this output :**

**

[image]

i had not written any code to display in starting of page still showing that ...

how to resolve that problem .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller function to:

```
public function view()
{
   $data = $this->db->get("cars")->result_array();
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

You're sending json from the controller. but if you don't specify it, it's send as the default type which would be html i believe and that's why it's printed on your page.

Even better is if you use:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

using `output` is the right way to deal with output data in codeigniter controllers.

Comment: nop.. its showing whole content  with page in output

Comment: this code is not helpful in my case any other solution

Comment: what happens if you use the `$this->output->..` way? does it still show the json on your page?

Comment: yh json show and whole page html content  and angular js content also shows like text

may i upload screen shot here

Comment: what do you mean angular content shows like text? are you saying instead of values of variables, the name of variables in {} are appearing on the page?

Comment: yh after adding this code in controller->view()

$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));

in reponse page getting whole code like

Comment: check in console(ctrl+shift+i on chrome) and see if you can find an angular error showing there.

Comment: [{"id":"33","cname":"sss","cimage":"Screenshot from 2016-08-22 11:06:13.png"},{"id":"34","cname":"sss","cimage":"Screenshot from 2016-08-22 11:06:13.png"}, .........
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>.......        
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
        <form method="post"  ng-submit="add(car_det)">
           ....
        </form>
        <br>
        <table>....</table>
        ................

Comment: no no..that's probably your page source. i am saying in console. press ctrl+shift+i you'll see a panel open up at bottom. click on the console tab on top, and check if you can find erros in the panel under it.

Comment: yh still showing while content json array, html page while content and angularjs content 

i am try to copy paste but here character limit so cant here 

but i tried in above comment 

see that

Comment: no in console done not shows error but after body there showing

<pre> tag

Comment: echo json_encode($data);    

i think problem with echo json_encode() because it showing on top of 
page but if had used return place of echo does not getting output showing blank in response.data

Answer (score 0):

If your view page is a html page then you have to define a global variable `baseUrl` where you need to write static `base_url()` value like this

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost/yourProjectName/';
```

If this your page is php page then defiine a hidden input tag and this value is `base_url();` and inside script write

```
var baseUrl = $('#inputId').val();
```

then your script like this..

```
app.controller("myctrl",function($scope,$http){
    $http.get(baseUrl+'Car/view').then(function(response){
       $scope.otherdata = response.data;
    });         
});
```

Comment: problem is not of baseurl its work proper just starting of page json array shows

Comment: I think your response data from controller is not correct.Just return an array from model and echo json_decode the array.

Comment: how is it possible ?

Comment: Just write $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $data; in your controller